# How to customize or delegate TcpNetClientConnectionFactory as TCP connection pool in spring integration

Tags: java, tcp, spring-integration

I am trying to implement/delegate my own TCP connection pool using the class TcpNetClientConnectionFactory for client tcp connection. Below is my bean definition and I've injected it in my outbound adapter. I am also using ThreadLocal to get the dynamic host that comes with the message so I'll be able to communicate it with the factory. I would like to have the connection factory (subclass of TcpNetClientConnectionFactory) to create/build a new connection again depending on the host provided in the message.

Though, I have no idea what is the best practice or approach for this scenario. If anyone could help, it would be very much appreciated.

```
<bean id="client2" class="com.xxx.yyy.connection.MyTcpNetClientConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="localhost" />
    <constructor-arg value="1234" />
    <constructor-arg value="false" />
    <constructor-arg value="10000" />
    <constructor-arg value="false" />
    <property name="serializer" ref="fastestWireFormatSerializer"></property>
    <property name="deserializer" ref="fastestWireFormatSerializer"></property>
</bean>

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter
    id="outAdapter" 
    channel="outChannel"
    connection-factory="client2" 
    />
```

This is the constructor for TcpNetClientConnectionFactory:

```
public MyTcpNetClientConnectionFactory(String host, int port, 
    boolean singleUse, int soTimeout, boolean soKeepAlive) {....}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by setting the "single-use" property to true.